# How to input PHP inside Javascript that is inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php, string, auto-generate

My problem is a bit, let's say original, I'll admit. Nevertheless, it's starting to bug me. I have a PHP program that needs to generate Javascript, nothing original in that you might say.

And I would agree, but it happens that the generated Javascript needs to use PHP variable and when I try to do so, Javascript thinks that I am giving him a string, as he should.

So I am kind of stuck, and I don't know how I could force Javascript to understand that I am giving him PHP and not a string. I've already searched for the solution of course, but all I could find was people trying to generate Javascript through PHP or the other way around. My problem is one step further and you might call it : inception.

Here is a code example of what I am trying to accomplish :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<?php
$lat = 46.779231;
$lng = 6.659431;
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        var carte;
            function initialiser() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.779231, 6.659431);
                var options = {
                    center: latlng,
                    zoom: 19,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                carte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\"carte\"), options);
                /*var marqueur = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(46.779231, 6.659431),
                    map: carte
                });*/
            }
        var lat = \"<?php echo $lat; ?>\";
        var lng = \"<?php echo $lng; ?>\";
        alert(lat);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map: carte
        });
    </script>";
?>
```

The problem is on the two following lines:

```
var lat = \"<?php echo $lat; ?>\";
var lng = \"<?php echo $lng; ?>\";
```

Javascript thinks that lat and lng are two strings, do you have any idea on how to make him understand that it is actually PHP ?

Thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply concatenate them -

```
var lat = '".$lat."';
```

Comment: That was amazingly fast !

Comment: If they are numbers then no need of `'`s also. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `<script></script>` tag is already inside `<?php ... ?>` so you don't need to use `<?php ... ?>` again, just call the php variable directly like this :

```
var lat = \"$lat\";
var lng = \"$lng\";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<?php
$lat = 46.779231;
$lng = 6.659431;
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var carte;
        function initialiser() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.779231, 6.659431);
            var options = {
                center: latlng,
                zoom: 19,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            carte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\"carte\"), options);
            /*var marqueur = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(46.779231, 6.659431),
                map: carte
            });*/
        }
    var lat = ".$lat.";
    var lng = ".$lng.";
    alert(lat);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        map: carte
    });
</script>";
?>
```

or if required

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<?php
$lat = 46.779231;
$lng = 6.659431;
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var carte;
        function initialiser() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.779231, 6.659431);
            var options = {
                center: latlng,
                zoom: 19,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            carte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\"carte\"), options);
            /*var marqueur = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(46.779231, 6.659431),
                map: carte
            });*/
        }
    var lat = '".$lat."';
    var lng = '".$lng."';
    alert(lat);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        map: carte
    });
</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Why should OP use this? What have you changed? What did OP do wrong?